# Cooking duck Chinese style

Tags: food-safety

A Chinese style recipe for duck calls for seasoning the duck with salt, pepper and stuffing with ginger and scallion.  Then, hanging to dry at room temperature overnight before cooking.  Is this method safe? What about the temperature danger zone? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

That method would clearly place your duck in the temperature danger zone for too long.  The reason for hanging the duck, particularly after salting, is to dehydrate the skin as much as possible.  This results in a crispier skin.  Fortunately, you can achieve the same results in the refrigerator. Hanging is ideal, but this can also be accomplished on a rack. A couple of days is even better.  The idea is to expose as much of the skin to air (keep it off a plate) as possible.  The technique works well for chicken too. Put a plate or container under the rack or hanging bird to collect any liquid that might drip.

Comment: Keep in mind recipes like this are often for freshly killed animals which are left hanging for a while anyway. What you buy in the store however is not suitable for this treatment for several reasons include contamination to pathogens which are safe if left refrigerated but grow quickly at room temp.